# Am I obligated to refer to darkness as "it" in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

So I was writing a little something and I thought of this sentence:
"In darkness, I found a friend, and she held my hand."
At first, I referred to darkness as "it", but it felt like it didn't deliver the meaning quite well. But then again, English isn't my first language and I could be wrong.
Which do you think sounds better? And is my sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: If you're writing in a genre where it's permissible to personify darkness as a friend there can certainly no be no objection to extending that personification to the pronoun. ... I would kill the comma after darkness: it leads the reader to understand *in darkness* as a clausal modifier describing the scene where you found a friend rather.

Comment: I'm writing a YA fiction, so I guess I'll change it back to "it". Thank you for pointing out the comma, I'm not very good with punctuation 

Comment: Sajida, I’m amazed that anyone who could come up with such a beautiful phase as *In darkness, I found a friend, and she held my hand* would also stumble over *it didn't deliver the meaning quite well*.

Please don’t change it, *back* or anywhere else… if that meant *In darkness, I found a friend, and it held my hand* that would be horrible and how else could you change it? 

For clarity, the only thing just possible questionable about *darkness became my friend* is that anything personified, including *Darkness* deserves a capital.

Comment: Hello Robbie, thanks for your help. As I mentioned, I'm not a native speaker so the simplest things could go over my head sometimes.

Comment: I agree with the other commentators, referring to darkness as "she" is gorgeous, very poetic

Comment: I think the SHE on the senteces make a real difference. Beautiful.

Comment: [Under The Bridge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4x23l6BGu3w) uses the same idea, the lyrics refer to the city of Los Angeles with female pronouns: _"I drive on **her** streets cause **she**'s my companion. I walk through **her** hills cause **she** knows who I am."_

Comment: ‘‘Hello darkness, my old friend / I’ve come to talk with you again ...’’ — [The Sound Of Silence](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/simongarfunkel/thesoundofsilence.html)

Comment: You're making a poetic analogy.  You can use whatever terms you wish.

Answer (score 4):

No you are not.

> In darkness, I found a friend, and she held my hand.

As all commenters said, it is a good sentence just as it is.

Answer (score 4):

The only persons whos thoughts matter are your own. For my own opinion, this phrase is incredibly beautiful as is. Write it as you originally meant it. I have always thought of darkness as a 'he', but thats me.